# How do I create a scalable "View" button on my car sales website?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a car sales website for my final year project. The following is code for my catalogue page - it is a scalable car list with buttons to edit, and delete cars from my website and Firebase database. At the moment, one can click on the anchor and it will take you to the Item1.html page. I would like to make it so that if you click on the first item on the list, it will take you to Item1.html, the second item will be Item2.html and so on. The following is the code for the items listed on my catalogue page. Any help would be appreciated.

**Catalogue.html**

```
<div>
  <lo id="carList">
  </lo>
</div>
```

**Catalogue.js**

```
database.ref('car').once('value', function(snapshot){

    if(snapshot.exists()){
        var content = '';
        snapshot.forEach(function(data){
            var val = data.val();
            var key = data.key;

            content += '<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item"><div class="card h-100">**<a href="Item1.html">**<img class="card-img-top" src="'+val.image+'" alt=""></a><div class="card-body"><h4 class="card-title"><a href="Item1.html">'+val.make+'&nbsp'+val.model+'</a></h4><p class="card-text">Price: '+val.price+'</br>Year: '+val.year+'</br><button id="modify" onclick="update(\''+key+'\')">Modify</button><button id="deleted" onclick="deleted(\''+ key+'\')">Delete</button></p></div></div></div>';
        });

        $('#carList').append(content);
    }
});
```

Any advice/alternative ways I can do this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

change this

```
 snapshot.forEach(function(data){
```

to this:

```
 var cntr = 0;
 snapshot.forEach(function(data,index){
     cntr++;
```

and change this

```
<a href="Item1.html">
```

to

```
<a href="Item' + cntr + '.html">
```

Comment: Just tried this and page not working, unfortunately.

Comment: @DannyO'Sullivan when you do it, what is it doing that makes it not working? Is there an error?

Comment: when I click on it, it takes me to a page which says - "This page is not working. localhost didn't send any data." It used to take me to Item1.html.

Comment: @DannyO'Sullivan I updated my answer, I assumed key was a different value than it is.

Comment: having the same problem when I add the index part. Is there something else that I need to add right underneath to make the index work?

Comment: When you click on the page, in your address bar what does it say?